# using beautifulsoup to get second and third child in BeautifuSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a table similar to below:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
        <tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I need the second and third  of each row.  I am using BeautifulSoup in Python 3.5

Right now, I'm doing:

```
Table = Soup.find('table', attrs={'id': 'field'})
        Tbody = Table.find('tbody')
        Records = Tbody.find_all('tr')
        Record = Records.find_all('td')
        for field in Records:
            print (Record[2].text)
```

I am receiving the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/arcee/PycharmProjects/scraper/main.py", line 33, in <module>
    Record = Records.find_all('td')
AttributeError: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'find_all'
```

Is there an easier way to get the Second and third TD elements?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're getting that error because of these lines:

```
Records = Tbody.find_all('tr')
Record = Records.find_all('td')
```

`find_all` returns a `list` (`ResultSet`) of occurrences of the searched tag.  The `ResultSet` doesn't have a `find_all` attribute - but each individual member of it does.  so, doing..

```
Records = Tbody.find_all('tr')
for record in records:
    print(record.find_all('td'))
```

will make your code run.

Comment: ok.  this is good.  Thank you so much